# React native - cant see podfile in xcode

Tags: xcode, react-native-ios

I created a react native app using react native cli.
When I use finder to navigate into ios folder I can see podfile.....however when I open the project in xcode I cant see it anywhere.
Any idea why?

**UPDATE 4/29** - I tried answer below to "Open the xcworkspace file with Xcode not the xcproj one"....and this did not work.  Regardless of which file I use to open, I still dont see podfile (or xcworkspace file for that matter)

Im using Xcode 12.5.....and a macbook air with the new M1 chip (I mention this because the M1 chip has been causing me a host of other problems like not being able to download IOS simulator)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open the xcworkspace file with Xcode not the xcproj one.

Comment: As per above unfortunately this did not work

Answer (score 0):

I ended up exchanging my macbook air with M1 chip....for an older one with Intel chip.  All the issues I was facing before are no longer.

My advice is to not purchase any laptop with M1 chip until Apple have had time to figure out all the bugs that occur for developers (M1 chip was only launched last Nov and theres still SO many issues for devs).